# pydbus: How to publish an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dbus

I want to publish a python object on a session bus, using **pydbus** and **python 2.7**. I'm new to pydbus, so I stick to the example and did the tutorial. However, I did not manage to launch a simply test server with pydbus.

I wrote a simple class, with only one method, which returns a string. I specified an interface and created an event loop.

**code:**

```
from pydbus import SessionBus
from gi.repository import GObject

loop = GObject.MainLoop()

class Testclass(object):
    """
    <node>
        <interface name='org.philipp.DBUSTutorial'>
            <method name='helloworld'>
                <arg type='s' name='reply' direction='out'/>
            </method>
        </interface>
    </node>
    """

    def helloworld():
        return "Hello World"

bus = SessionBus()
bus.publish("org.philipp.DBUSTutorial", Testclass())
loop.run()
```

After executing the script it throws an error.

**error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    bus.publish("org.philipp.DBUSTutorial", Testclass())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydbus/publication.py", line 33, in publish
    return Publication(self, bus_name, *objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydbus/publication.py", line 26, in __init__
    self._at_exit(bus.register_object(path, object, node_info).__exit__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydbus/registration.py", line 123, in register_object
    return ObjectRegistration(self.con, path, interfaces, wrapper, own_wrapper=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydbus/registration.py", line 103, in __init__
    ids = [con.register_object(path, interface, wrapper.call_method, wrapper.get_property, wrapper.set_property) for interface in interfaces]
TypeError: argument vtable: Expected Gio.DBusInterfaceVTable, but got pydbus.registration.instancemethod
```

What am I doing wrong? It would be great, if somebody could help me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in Readme:
"Since 0.5, it supports publishing objects on the bus - however this requires GLib 2.46 or newer."

Unfortunately there is no way to publish objects with older GLib.

Answer (score 0):

To register a dbus object :

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

class Foo(dbus.service.Object):
"""
"""
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(bus, path)

    # A method
    @dbus.service.method(<dbus_interface_name>,
                         in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def foo(self):
        pass
```